# Memory Overload Error running a long ambiguous sequence due to (sre.yield_AllStrings)

Tags: python, memory, sequence, biopython

I was hoping someone could help me out.

I'm trying to make a function that given an (un)ambiguous DNA sequence and a molecular weight interval, returns a list of all unambiguous sequences represented by the given sequence.

So far I've come up with:

```
import re
import sre_yield
from Bio import SeqIO
import Bio.SeqUtils
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import Bio.SeqIO
    
def all_seq_between_upper_lower_mw(file, lower_mw, upper_mw):
    file = SeqIO.read(file,'fasta')
    sequence = file.seq
    seqs_opt = Bio.SeqUtils.nt_search("", sequence)
    seqs = list(sre_yield.AllStrings(seqs_opt[0]))
    if (len(seqs) == 1):
        print("This sequence is unambiguous")
        mol_weight = Bio.SeqUtils.molecular_weight(results[0])
        if mol_weight > lower_mw and mol_weight < upper_mw:
            print("Nucleotide sequence: "+str(seqs[0])+"  &  molecular weight = "+str(mol_weight))
        else:
            print(" This sequence is not within the given molecular weight limits")
    else:
        print("This sequence is ambiguous")
        results = dict()
        for record in seqs:
            results[record] = Bio.SeqUtils.molecular_weight(record)
        possibility_counter = 0
        for seq, mol_weight in results.items():
            possibility_counter += 1
            if mol_weight > lower_mw and mol_weight < upper_mw:
                print("Possibility "+str(possibility_counter)+": "+str(seq)+" & molecular weight = "+str(mol_weight))
            else:
                print("Possibility "+str(possibility_counter)+": This sequence  is not within the given molecular weight limits")
```

This code runs perfectly given a short, (un)ambiguous sequence. But when given an ambiguous sequence that's quite long, it gives the error: Memory overload, which points to the sre.yield_AllStrings function.

For reference, short ambiguous sequence FASTA file:

```
>seq_7009 random sequence
DGRGGGWAVCVAACGTTGAT
```

long ambiguous sequence FASTA file:

```
>seq_445 random sequence
ARYGNTAVHGAMRRACNTNHSGVYGVRCGAGAHTGVBCKWACACAGTKYCACGBGAGGYGTCCGYTGVGASCC
```

I'm still new to Python, but I hope that someone might know how to solve the Memory Error.

Comment: what does : seqs_opt = Bio.SeqUtils.nt_search("", sequence) do ???

Comment: with the long sequence : print(len((sre_yield.AllStrings(seqs_opt[0])))) gives : 123834728448 as output, maybe adding more memory to your machine will fix it somehow  ? ;-)

Comment: try to convert code in:  for sequence in sre_yield.AllStrings(seqs_opt[0]): do something to each sequence without creating the huge list in memory

Comment: This transforms IUPAC ambiguous letters into a regular expression. The AllStrings function can therefore transform the sequence into a list. Hope that answers your question

Comment: yep thank you, had a look at it. 123834728448 sequences out of the longest fasta, try to work on each of it one at a time. Extracting them and processing one by one from the sre_yield.AllStrings() generator (is it a generator ? don,t know but you can loop over it )

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I now realised it is kind of impossible to do this in a short amount of time :')